# Encountered a syntax error while rendering template when using alpinejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using alpinejs with ROR and getting template error for below statement.

Please help me to resolve it.

```
 <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" :class => "{ 'bg-gray-100': activeIndex === 2 }", role: "menuitem", tabindex: "-1", id:"user-menu-item-2" , @mouseenter: "activeIndex = 2", @mouseleave: "activeIndex = -1", @click: "open = false; focusButton()" do%> Logout <% end %>
```

Regards,
Kiran

Comment: In Ruby hashes use the json style `class:` syntax or hashrockets (`:class =>`). `class=` is a syntax error. You also can't start barewords in the JSON syntax with `@` so you need to use `:@mouseenter => "activeIndex = 2"`. Even if you fix that error you're still passing the option for class twice. One protip is the you can actually split your code into multiple lines of aprropriate length so that you can actually read the code and solve the issues yourself. https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html

Comment: `"{ 'bg-gray-100': activeIndex === 2 }"` is also not a valid CSS class so no idea what you're trying to do with that one.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's because you use `class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700"` instead of `class: "block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700"`, it's occur an error IIRC